# How to disable vertical text spacing?

Tags: spacing, formatting, multicol

I have been making some notes for a math class in LaTeX and I was wondering if there was a way to disable the automatic vertical spacing. I am writing the document in three columns and it seems to spread some sections over an entire column to fill it. If there is a way to fix this, please help. (Note: I have not made any changed to the default text alignment, this happened automatically.)

[image: The vertical padding spread the text in some columns out very far.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do please also tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: everything happens due to commands in your document, here you are presumably using a document class that you have not specified that defaults to `\flushbottom` when you want `\raggedbottom`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written in the documentation multicol has its own controls for ragged and aligned columns called `\raggedcolumns` and `\flushcolumns`, the default is the latter. They are applied if a multicols spans several pages, regardless of what the document uses elsewhere (i.e., `\raggedbottom` does not apply then). It also has controls for handling the last column specially when balancing, see `texdoc multicol`.